# Why am I receiving the "zsh: exec format error: ./metal" error?

Tags: zsh, executable, error-handling

I am attempting to run a Unix executable program (Metal; https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/METAL_Quick_Start) from the terminal. I continue to get the following error: zsh: exec format error.

I have ensured the program file format is "Unix executable" and do not have this issue when attempting to run a different Unix executable program such as plink2 (https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I have ensured the program file format is "Unix executable"

How exactly did you ensure that? I mean, it can still be a "Unix executable", just not executable on your particular machine. (Like, trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit system, or a binary built for a different libc, etc.)

How did you obtain that binary? Was it through the standard package install tools of your distro, or did you just copy the binary from some place else?

When you're in the directory where `metal` resides, run these commands:

```
ls -la metal
file metal
ldd metal
uname -a
```

...and tell us what you see.